# Alternative to using Future.sequence inside Akka Actors

Tags: scala, akka, future, actor

We have a fairly complex system developed using Akka HTTP and Actors model. Until now, we extensively used ask pattern and mixed Futures and Actors.

For example, an actor gets message, it needs to execute 3 operations in parallel, combine a result out of that data and returns it to sender. What we used is

1. declare a new variable in actor receive message callback to store a **sender** (since we use Future.map it can be another sender).
2. executed all those 3 futures in parallel using Future.sequence (sometimes its call of function that returns a future and sometimes it is **ask** to another actor to get something from it)
3. combine the result of all 3 futures using **map** or **flatMap** function of Future.sequence result
4. pipe a final result to a sender using pipeTo

Here is a code simplified:

```
case RetrieveData(userId, `type`, id, lang, paging, timeRange, platform) => {
      val sen = sender

      val result: Future[Seq[Map[String, Any]]] = if (paging.getOrElse(Paging(0, 0)) == Paging(0, 0)) Future.successful(Seq.empty)
      else {
        val start = System.currentTimeMillis()

        val profileF = profileActor ? Get(userId)

        Future.sequence(Seq(profileF, getSymbols(`type`, id), getData(paging, timeRange, platform)).map { result =>
          logger.info(s"Got ${result.size} news in ${System.currentTimeMillis() - start} ms")
          result
        }.recover { case ex: Throwable =>
          logger.error(s"Failure on getting data: ${ex.getMessage}", ex)
          Seq.empty
        }
      }

      result.pipeTo(sen)
    }
```

Function **getAndProcessData** contains Future.sequence with executing 3 futures in parallel.

Now, as I'm reading more and more on Akka, I see that using ask is creating another actor listener. Questions are:

1. As we extensively use ask, can it lead to a to many threads used in a system and perhaps a thread starvation sometimes?
2. Using Future.map much also means different thread often. I read about one thread actor illusion which can be easily broken with mixing Futures.
3. Also, can this affect performances in a bad way?
4. Do we need to store sender in temp variable send, since we're using pipeTo? Could we do only pipeTo(sender). Also, does declaring sen in almost each receive callback waste to much resources? I would expect its reference will be removed once operation in complete.
5. Is there a chance to design such a system in a better way, meadning that we don't use map or ask so much? I looked at examples when you just pass a **replyTo** reference to some actor and the use tell instead of ask. Also, sending message to self and than replying to original sender can replace working with Future.map in some scenarios. But how it can be designed having in mind we want to perform 3 async operations in parallel and returns a formatted data to a sender? We need to have all those 3 operations completed to be able to format data.

I tried not to include to many examples, I hope you understand our concerns and problems. Many questions, but I would really love to understand how it works, simple and clear

Thanks in advance

Comment: `paging.getOrElse(Paging(0, 0)) == Paging(0, 0)` => `paging.forall(_ == Paging(0,0))`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do 3 things in parallel you are going to need to create 3 `Future` values which will potentially use 3 threads, and that can't be avoided.

I'm not sure what the issue with `map` is, but there is only one call in this code and that is not necessary.

Here is one way to clean up the code to avoid creating unnecessary `Future` values (untested!):

```
case RetrieveData(userId, `type`, id, lang, paging, timeRange, platform) =>
  if (paging.forall(_ == Paging(0, 0))) {
    sender ! Seq.empty
  } else {
    val sen = sender
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()

    val resF = Seq(
      profileActor ? Get(userId),
      getSymbols(`type`, id),
      getData(paging, timeRange, platform),
    )

    Future.sequence(resF).onComplete {
      case Success(result) =>
        val dur = System.currentTimeMillis() - start
        logger.info(s"Got ${result.size} news in $dur ms")

        sen ! result
      case Failure(ex)
        logger.error(s"Failure on getting data: ${ex.getMessage}", ex)

        sen ! Seq.empty
    }
  }
```

You can avoid `ask` by creating your own worker thread that collects the different results and then sends the result to the sender, but that is probably more complicated than is needed here.

Answer (score 2):

An actor only consumes a thread in the dispatcher when it is processing a message.  Since the number of messages the actor spawned to manage the ask will process is one, it's very unlikely that the ask pattern by itself will cause thread starvation.  If you're already very close to thread starvation, an ask might be the straw that breaks the camel's back.

Mixing `Future`s and actors can break the single-thread illusion, if and only if the code executing in the `Future` accesses actor state (meaning, basically, `var`s or mutable objects defined outside of a `receive` handler).

Request-response and at-least-once (between them, they cover at least most of the motivations for the ask pattern) will in general limit throughput compared to at-most-once tells.  Implementing request-response or at-least-once without the ask pattern might in some situations (e.g. using a `replyTo` `ActorRef` for the ultimate recipient) be less overhead than piping asks, but probably not significantly.  Asks as the main entry-point to the actor system (e.g. in the streams handling HTTP requests or processing messages from some message bus) are generally OK, but asks from one actor to another are a good opportunity to streamline.

Note that, especially if your actor imports `context.dispatcher` as its implicit `ExecutionContext`, transformations on `Future`s are basically identical to single-use actors.

Situations where you want multiple things to happen (especially when you need to manage partial failure (`Future.sequence.recover` is a possible sign of this situation, especially if the `recover` gets nontrivial)) are potential candidates for a saga actor to organize one particular request/response.

Comment: Thanks very much. That's exactly what we use. We use multiple actors, asking them on each request (we use Akka Http framework for web server), combine their responses into single response and returns it to client. However, there are few examples in our system where we could use tell instead of ask. I'll do that for sure!

Comment: Can you please also refered to question 4 from my original post?

Comment: Yes, you need to preserve `sender` because it is a `var` in the actor and may have changed by the time the `Future` completes. (This is why Typed Actors don't have a `sender` and you have to put the return address in the message)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest instead of using Future.sequence, Souce from Akka can be used which will run all the futures in parallel, in which you can provide the parallelism also.
Here is the sample code:

```
Source.fromIterator( () => Seq(profileF, getSymbols(`type`, id), getData(paging, timeRange, platform)).iterator )
        .mapAsync( parallelism = 1 ) { case (seqIdValue, row) =>
          row.map( seqIdValue -> _ )
        }.runWith( Sink.seq ).map(_.map(idWithDTO => idWithDTO))
```

This will return Future[Seq[Map[String, Any]]]

Comment: This seems to be a lot of extra code with no obvious advantage.

Comment: Its just an alternative and a better way of not using Future.sequence as using Future.sequence will involve usage of extra threads which I think should be avoided and using Source from Akka is a better way of avoiding that

Comment: `Future.sequence` will create a new `Future` but that is not the same as creating a new thread. I suspect that the `Source` version uses as many if not more resources and threads than `Future.sequence`

Comment: Future.sequence will run one by one and will wait until previous future is not complete. Using source with mapSync, futures can work in parallel and will complete be faster. Also what if an error is encountered in between sequential execution of futures, it will start again. But Akka handles this quite well.

Comment: No, this is incorrect. A `Future` is available for execution as soon as it is created, so all the `Future`s begin executing when the `Seq` is created and before it gets passed to either your code or my code. The only difference between the two is how the code waits for them all to complete, and this is exactly what `Future.sequence` was designed for.